# Custom Action for Composer 2.0 bot not executing

Tags: node.js, typescript, botframework, bot-framework-composer

I'm attempting to implement the MultiplyDialog example using the Node Runtime as a demo for future custom actions.

Code related to this question can be found here: https://github.com/alexstojda/adaptive-dialogs-custom-action

**The problem:** The dialog never executes (MultiplyDialog.beginDialog(...) is never called)

I followed these instructions to setup the custom action, making relevant adjustments for use in node where applicable, notably:

1. Installing the MultiplyDialog package using `npm install ../multiply_dialog_package` from within `empty_bot`
2. Updating `empty_bot/settings/appsettings.json` to include the component:

```
  "runtimeSettings": {
    ...
    "components": [
      {
        "name": "multiply-dialog-package" 
      }
    ],
  }
```

The bot starts with no errors, and the component's `configureServices` is called, but when the Dialog is called, there is [no log output in the console](https://github.com/alexstojda/adaptive-dialogs-custom-action/blob/39180643c50a50c7ec8760dfa39b4e9bc72dac15/multiply_dialog_package/src/multiplyDialog.ts#L61), and `dialog.result` remains undefined in the next step of the action.

Any advice or help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution provided by @joshgummersall via GitHub

> Hey @alexstojda,
>
> I tend to use yarn workspaces for development work. It's a more
> reliable way of linking together local packages for development. In
> this case, that was all I needed to do to get the multiply dialog
> working locally using the Bot Framework Emulator. To test this out:
>
> ```
> $ cd path/to/repo 
> $ git pull 
> $ npm install -g yarn 
> $ yarn 
> $ yarn dev I
> ```
>
> Tested this inside a Vagrant VM to ensure I had a clean system.